# How did the meaning of "lifting" in proof assistants arise?

Tags: history, terminology

In topology, the notion of "lifting" has a [quite a long history](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/3136/history-of-covering-spaces), starting with the theory of covering spaces, where the classic example is that if you take an outdoor spiral staircase, $S$ and look at its shadow at noontime, you see a circle, $C$. "Casting a shadow" gives a map $p : S\to C$ with lots of nice properties, and we say that $S$ is a covering of $C$. $C$ is the base space, $S$ is the covering space, and $p$ is the projection.

A typical problem we consider is this: suppose we have a point $c \in C$ and a point $s \in S$ with $p(s) = c$. If we have a path in $C$ starting at $c$ (i.e., a function $u: [0, 1] \to C$ with $u(0) = c$), is there a path $\hat{u}$ in $S$ that "covers" $u$, i.e., a function
$$
\hat{u}:[0, 1] \to S,\\
\hat{u}(0) = s \\
p(\hat{u}(t)) = u(t) \text{ for $0 \le t \le 1$ }.
$$

In humbler terms, if Ann takes a walk on the circle starting at $c$, can Robin take a walk on the staircase starting at $s$ in such a way that Robin's shadow falls on Ann at all times?

The answer (at least in this example) is evidently "yes", and that's called the "path lifting theorem" --- the path $\hat{u}$ is a "lift" of the path $u$. That gets generalized to the homotopy lifting theorem, etc.

It's pretty clear that on $S$, there's an equivalence relation defined by $p$: points $s_1$ and $s_2$ are declared equivalent when $p(s_1) = p(s_2)$. Under this equivalence relation, the set $C$ is the quotient of $S$ by this relation.

So we have a set $S$, a relation $\sim$ on $S$, and a quotient $C = S/\sim$. A function $u$ to the set $C$ is said to "lift" to a function $\hat{u}$ to $S$.

This is exactly the opposite of the use of "lift" in both Lean and Isabelle, as far as I can tell. In those, we start with a function to $S$ and "lift" it to a function to $C$ (if certain conditions hold).  A topologist would describe this second one by saying "we have a function going to $S$; is it the lift of a function to $C$?

There's a kind of "dual" notion: perhaps we have a function $f$ from $S$ to some space $X$. If $f(x) = f(y)$ whenever $p(x) = p(y)$, then topologists would say that $f$ "passes to (or even "projects to") a function on the quotient", while proof-assistant folks seem to say that $f$ *lifts* to a function on $C$.

Can anyone explain how this exactly-opposite notion of "lift" arose for proof-assistants? I know that lots of words in mathematics get used differently in different context, but I can't think of many instances where the meanings are exact opposites (except for some confusion over co-variant and contra-variant).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I totally agree that Lean's `quotient.lift` is disastrously-named as far as mathematicians are concerned. After discussion with the Lean devs it seems that it came about because to a computer scientist, quotienting out something by an equivalence relation is "making it more complex" (because as a type the quotient involves more stuff than the original type), whereas for mathematicians it's "making it smaller and hence simpler".

Comment: Today I learned that in mathematics the circle is simpler than the straight line.

Comment: The circle is compact, the line is not.

Comment: Thanks, Kevin. That makes some (unfortunate) sense. It's probably too late to go back and fix it, alas.

Comment: Well...this same naming disaster has been present in Isabelle for quite a long time, and it doesn't seem to have been fixed in any way.

Comment: It's worth noting that in mathematics the term "lift" is part of 3 compatible conventions: "lift", "descent" (for more-or-less what Lean calls "lift"), and writing morphisms as a vertical arrow point downwards.

Comment: @AndrejBauer Except in homotopy theory, the circle and the straight line are about equally complex - for example, they are each the unique isomorphism class of objects with their basic properties. A more clear-cut example might be hyperbolic manifolds, which really are much simpler than their universal covers. Almost every principle has exceptions!

Comment: @WillSawin: I would add "passes to the quotient" as another part of that set. As you know, when $X$ "quotients to" $Y$ via some function $p$, there are two separate problems: (1) GIven a map $f$ from $A$ to $Y$, is there a map $F$ from $A$ to $X$ with $p \circ F = f$? (2) Given a map $G$ from $Y$ to $A$, is there a map $g:X \to A$ with $g = p  \circ G$? For case 2, I'd say that $G$ "passes to the quotient; for case $1$, I'd say that $f$ "lifts" to $F$ (although that's really a special case). The proof-assistant doc'n I've seen would be improved by noting these.

Comment: @John The specific point I was making with the conventions is that they all use a common visual metaphor, which "passes to the quotient" doesn't, but it's certainly not incompatible with them. (Probably "descent" is not so commonly used outside algebraic geometry and related fields.) I agree such issues should be mentioned in the docs...

Comment: Ah...I see your point. As I wrote "passes to the quotient" I was, of course, *thinking* of the vertical metaphor, which probably comes from covering-spaces originally. :)